# Why can't I commit transactions with Caliper to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I've got Caliper configured as a subtree of my custom Fabric blockchain. I have it configured correctly in order to connect the network and am running a small set of tests at the moment. The arguments I'm providing are absolutely correct in terms of the custom chaincode being run, but whenever I try to create a transaction via Caliper I get the error:

`Failed to perform submit transaction [CreateAsset] using arguments [<ARGS>],  with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Anybody encountered this before with Caliper V0.4.2? It's interfacing with a Fabric 2.3.3 instance on local machine via Kubernetes, with the latest SDK bound.

The error occurs on line 237 of transactions.js inside the node_module fabric-network, where there is a strict property comparison on a commit object.

Also it's worth noting that the querying part of my test rounds is yielding expected results... none of those assets get created due to the error thrown, and when querying for a given asset an error like so occurs:

`Failed to perform query transaction [ReadAsset] using arguments [<ID>],  with error: Error: error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: Error: The asset <ID> does not exist`

The closest thing I've been able to find is this ~2 year old issue which isn't exactly what I'm facing but it's the same sort of error at least... any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated because I'm struggling to glean useful information. (Link: https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper/issues/727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the host names being converted to localhost when you want to work anything except a network running locally via docker. You need to launch caliper with the following extra option

```
--caliper-fabric-gateway-localhost false
```

Comment: of course, you're correct! Thanks so much for taking the time over the RocketChat for Caliper to help me diagnose this issue the other day. It's on my agenda to submit an issue/PR for this and for the minor bug found in the Fabric Node SDK, too.